# problem with google-libphonenumber when work with country code +39 06

Tags: javascript

I have problem with this lib.
first I chose country number from input: +3906.
Then I add phone number 4545.
After that I merge them together (+39064545).

When I need to split them (country number and phone number) I can't do it with google-libphonenumber.(country number: 39, phone number: 64545)

```
var countryCode = "3906";
var phoneNum = "4545";
var phoneNumber = "+" + countryCode + phoneNum;
var phoneUtil = libphonenumber.PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();

PhoneNumber = phoneUtil.parse(phoneNumber);

mobileCountry = phoneNumber["1"];

console.log(mobileCoutry);
```

Any suggest please. Thanks for reading.

Comment: can you please share the full code

Comment: I can show a little bit of it because this is my real project.

Comment: From [doc](https://github.com/google/libphonenumber#mapping-phone-numbers-to-original-carriers), you can manually specify `new PhoneNumber().setCountryCode(3906).setNationalNumber(4545);`

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the **phone Number** like below and then you can read the properties **conuntryCallingCode** and **nationalNumber** of phone number to get the values you desired.

Helpful for me was the following https://www.npmjs.com/package/libphonenumber-js

```
let parsePhoneNumber  = require('libphonenumber-js') ;

const phoneNumber = parsePhoneNumber('+ 3906 4545', 'VA')


console.log(phoneNumber.countryCallingCode); // 39
console.log(phoneNumber.nationalNumber); // 064545
```

Comment: I found the problem is format of the phone number, if you need Vatican phone number, your phone number must have +39 06 698. any way thanks very much.

Comment: why 698 and not 4545? I found this 4545 for Vatican

Comment: Alex please let me know your google-lib's version. I have tried some random version and it didn't work.

Comment: @NguyễnThanhBình I can not check it at the moment but probably the current one from the link which I have linked 1.9.7